# Splitting and combining only parts of a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string for example: `https://192.168.22.34/www/index.html`

I only want to extract the last 2 parts of the IP address i.e `2234` to make a port number.

Currently, I am doing:

```
port = url.split('.').slice(2,4).join("").split('/').slice(0,1).join("");
```

Is there a cleaner method to do it? Or this is the best I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```js
var url = 'https://192.168.22.34/www/index.html'
port = url.split('/')[2].split('.').slice(2,4).join('');

console.log(port);
```

It is also possible do the same using regular expressions:

```js
var url = 'https://192.168.22.34/www/index.html'
port = url.match(/\d{1,3}/g).slice(2,4).join('');

console.log(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the host, apply a regex on it and extract the required vars:

```
const url = 'https://192.168.22.34/www/index.html';    

const [,,a,b] = new URL(url).host.match(/\d{2,3}/g);

console.log(`${a}${b}`);
```